# végan ou végane?

Tags: anglais, adjectifs, accord, alimentation

Doit-on considerer le mot "vegan" emprunté de l'anglais comme un adjectif que s'accorde avec un object masculin ou féminin:

> le garçon végan
>   le fille végane

Ou doit-on toujours écrire végane et ainsi éviter une mauvaise prononciation du suffixe "an"?

> le garçon dégante
>   la fille végane

Merci !

Comment: La réponse est sur le site http://www.vegan-france.fr.  En français il est convenu d'adapter les termes "vegan" et "vegans" en "végane" et "véganes".   **Végane** : Personne qui exclut de son alimentation tout produit d'origine animale (végétalien) et adopte un mode de vie respectueux des animaux (habillement, cosmetiques, loisirs...). **Adj**. Le mouvement végane, véganisme (Définition Le Petit Robert 2015).

Comment: C'est une faute de frappe pour "dégante" ?

Comment: @Onaeu. Si je te suis bien tu renvoies à *végétalien*. Mais pour les "pratiquants" être *végétalien* et être *vegane* sont deux attitudes différentes. Être *végétalien* c'est  ne manger que des produits  issus du monde végétal. Être *vegane* c'est être végétalien **plus**  l'adoption d'un mode de vie qui exclut l'utilisation de produits issus d'animaux (tissus, cosmétiques, produits ménagers, etc.) et qui milite activement pour la protection du monde animal.

Comment: @Onaeu. En France je n'ai jamais rencontré à ce jour l'emploi de végétalien intégral préconisé par le GTD. Faut dire qu'en France, contrairement à d'autres pays que je connais (le RU surtout), le mouvement est peu répandu, il est juste en "voie d'expansion".

Comment: @user41746 You can say vegan for both a girl / boy but in french we usually say 'végétarien' instead of vegan. 'Végétalien' is a second term used in french which means they don't eat anything that come from animals : Un végétarien eat eggs / Un végétalien does not eat eggs.

Comment: @SteevenBrunner végétarien is very different from vegan (English or french) please refer to my comment to onaeu. Being vegan is a way of life that goes far beyond the mere fact of eating ony vegetables.

Comment: La question de l'OP se résume à la suivante : est-ce un emprunt ou un barbarisme ?

Comment: @GéraudBenazet Il semble que l'OP ne soit pas très coopératif, il ne nous a fournit aucune réponse aux commentaires... Il est peut-être déjà parti, qui sait...

Answer (score 1):

Vegetarian = végétarien (with dairy) / végétalien (without dairy)

Vegan = Végan

```
Un garçon végan
Une fille végane
```

The veganism in french "véganisme" is in the french dictionary only since 2013/2014... Some accept the difference in gender, while some use "végane" for both genders!

Comment: While I agree that "végétalien" should have been the french translation for vegan, quite a bit of the actual french vegetarian/vegan are very opiniated about veganism being a way of life going farther than just eating habits - ie : not using any animal product (even sheep wool for clothing) -. As "végétalien" is already defined as "not eating any animal products", another term for this way of life is/was required.

Comment: In France vegan people call themseves *végan**e*** with an **e** (un garçon végane, une fille végane).   You can read the comments I wrote under the question Jul 30 at 8:37 and Jul 30 at 9:59 and Aug 1 at 12:45.   I said "Being vegan is a way of life that goes far beyond the mere fact of eating only vegetables. "

Comment: Wow !! yep sorry, I check and it's true, I didn't knew that the "Véganisme" is finally in the french dictionary !!

Answer (score 0):

Ce qu'on trouve au lexique varie. L'usage n'est pas fixé et l'on retrouve la forme au féminin *végan(e)*, ainsi que la forme épicène *végane*, quand on emploie ce terme...

---

Le mot anglais *vegan* ([*veg[etable] + an*](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=vegan) ; la syncope résulte du schisme aux États-Unis avec la *Vegetarian Society* dit *Wikipédia*) fait l'objet d'un usage sous la forme empruntée *végan(e)* ou, de manière épicène, *végane*, mais il n'est pas nécessairement recommandé ([Franceterme](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=vegan&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search) : *végétalisme intégral, végétalien(ne) intégral(e)* ; [GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8363506) : *idem*). On explique par exemple que :

> Bien que les termes *végan* et *végane* soient légitimés dans l'usage,
>   l'Office québécois de la langue française ne les retient pas puisque
>   ce sont des emprunts intégraux adaptés qui s'intègrent mal au système
>   morphosémantique du français et qui nuisent à l'implantation des
>   termes français existants.
>
> La forme régulière du féminin de *végan* est *végane*. Toutefois, la
>   forme *végane* est aussi attestée comme étant épicène et pouvant
>   désigner le masculin et le féminin.
>
> [Grand dictionnaire terminologique - GDT, *vegan*]

Quant au [*Larousse*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/v%C3%A9g%C3%A9talien_v%C3%A9g%C3%A9talienne/81253/difficulte) en ligne, il propose aussi *végétaliste*, épicène. D'autres sources documentent l'emploi de *végan* avec [*véganisme*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%A9ganisme) et on mentionne une nuance (mode de vie) au lexique par rapport au sens usuel (doctrine) du terme anglais *veganism* (*Wikipédia*). On dit que chez *Robert* on préfère la forme épicène *végane*, alors que *Hachette* préférerait l'accord en genre avec *végan(e)*. Voir aussi en [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/20323/v%C3%A9gan-ou-v%C3%A9gane#comment40009_20323). La [table](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vegan%2Cv%C3%A9gan%2Cv%C3%A9gane%2Cv%C3%A9g%C3%A9talien%2Cv%C3%A9g%C3%A9talienne%2Cv%C3%A9ganisme%2Cv%C3%A9g%C3%A9talisme&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvegan%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cv%C3%A9g%C3%A9talien%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cv%C3%A9g%C3%A9talienne%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cv%C3%A9g%C3%A9talisme%3B%2Cc0) est donc mise au sujet de l'[emprunt](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=emprunt%20int%C3%A9gral&T3.x=0&T3.y=0)...

On peut enrichir la langue en calquant un mot qui est lié à un évènement particulier dans un pays particulier avec des références culturelles particulières, ou avec un terme qui permet à tout francophone de comprendre naturellement de quoi il s'agit, comment on prononce, et comment on peut nuancer, en opposant par exemple le *végétarisme* traditionnel qu'on connaît au *végétalisme*, puis au *végétalisme intégral* dont il semble être question. La prononciation du suffixe [*-an*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-an#English) illustre par ailleurs qu'il ne s'agit tout simplement pas d'un suffixe en français, alors que le suffixe correspondant est [*-(i)en*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-ien) pour l'idée d'appartenance (comparer avec [*-iste*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-iste), pour réfléchir sur le choix de *Larousse*). À mon avis les hésitations dans l'usage et la difficulté avec le genre qu'on retrouve ici sont tributaires, outre sa nouveauté relative, du peu de cohérence du mot *végan* en français.

Comment: Je ne traite pas des sens exacts ni de l'utilité que pourrait avoir _végan_ pour distinguer _végétalisme_ (avec le L) et le _végétalisme intégral_ ; je ne suis pas assez familier avec le sujet. J'aimerais bien lire d'autres réponses...

Comment: Je pensais qu'on s'intéresserait davantage au sujet mais ça ne semble pas être le cas. Sans doute à cause de l'été.